# Remove option dynamically from jQuery Chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

This works well to add an option dynamically to a jQuery chosen select box;

```
var select = $('select', editor.field('cms_module_system_tenancies.tenant_id').node() );
var newOption = $('<option value="'+tenant_id+'" selected>'+tenant_forename+' '+tenant_surname+'</option>');
select.append(newOption);
select.trigger("chosen:updated");
```

But, I can't figure out how to reverse the action and remove that newly added item the next time I trigger the select list.

Is there a reverse of `select.append` which would remove the option from the list?

Comment: Well, there's [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), which would seem to be what you mean.

Comment: as @DavidThomas said .remove() is what you need .. but Its better to make a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/) cause I really can't imagine what you trying to do

Answer (score 19):

***Update jQuery Chosen Dynamically***

Try this:

***Remove all child nodes***

```
$('#selectBox').empty().append('<option value="0">-- Select --</option>');
```

Here we are first emptying the select box and then appending a default "Select" option.

***Remove a single child node***

```
$("#selectBox option[value='option1']").remove();
```

**Trigger *chosen:updated* after empty() or remove()**

```
$('#selectBox').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) this will insert first. reverse to append.